# twitter profile pic as background for a <div> instead of <img>

Tags: jquery, css, twitter

I'm using a twitter rotating feed script that I've customized, however the original can be found here if needed: http://www.webdevdoor.com/jquery/animated-twitter-feed-fade-rotation/

For the user profile picture I have the following code that works great:

```
feedHTML += '<div class="twitter-pic" style="display: inline-block;"><a href="https://twitter.com/'+tweetusername+'" target="_blank"><img src="'+profileimage+'"images/twitter-feed-icon.png" width="22" height="22" alt="twitter icon" style="vertical-align: middle;" /></a>&nbsp;<img src="assets/images/twitter_feed_icon.png" alt="bigscoots twitter" style="vertical-align:middle;" />&nbsp;</div>';
```

Now what I would like to do is display the image as a background image for a  instead of the . I've tried a few variations however for some reason none of them seem to work, any thoughts?

```
feedHTML += '<a href="https://twitter.com/'+tweetusername+'" target="_blank"><div style="vertical-align: middle; display: inline-block; width: 22px; height: 22px; background-image:url('+profileimage+'images/twitter-feed-icon.png);"></div></a><div style="display: inline-block;"><img src="assets/images/twitter_feed_icon.png" alt="bigscoots twitter" style="vertical-align:middle;" />&nbsp;</div>';
```

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: The URL inside background-image:url needs to be encapsulated in quotations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The URL inside background-image:url needs to be encapsulated in quotations

```
background-image:url("image.png");
```

Or specifically to your code:

```
background-image:url("'+profileimage+'images/twitter-feed-icon.png");
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply! I actually tried your suggestion before posting here and I couldn't get it to work. I tried to see if it works at all and made a new document and used the following code:

    <div style="background-image:url("test-image.jpg");">t</div>

The reason this didn't work was obviously because I'm using double quotation marks twice. The question is, how do I get the right quotation marks for my original code because I'm using both single and double quotation marks several times and it's kind of getting me confused.

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: i figured it out and it was very close to what you said, thanks!